# Swift: firebase observer, viewcontrollers, loop

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, viewcontroller

In My xcode project, I have 2 view controllers: A and B, they all connect to the same firebase reference nod, and listening to the same data.

My problem is, For example: if I go back and forth between these two viewcontrollers for 7 times (or as many times as I go back and forth between that A and B viewcontrollers) once I clicked  a button perform an action, a firebase oberserver is triggered, viewcontroller A is triggered for 7 times, because I added

> print("action is triggered")

On viewcontroller A, and this line is print 7 times in the debugger. I kept try to figure out why 7 times , where the count is saved ? I tried to remove firebse observer using the documents provided from Firebase, but no luck, maybe probelm is coming from shuttling back and forth between these view controllers. these viewcontroller is never been removed, but I never recall I need to remove viewcontroller! I  try to find any discussion here and google it, and I got no luck.

All I try to do is detect data change inside firebase database, if something changed in database, the button function changed and perform certain different function. All works fine, until I found out this loop  problem. Anyone ever encounter the same problem?

Comment: Hint: you want us to spend our time to help you solve your problem. So **format** matters. I gave up after 3 or 4 lines - this input is simply written in way that makes way too hard to digest. So please: edit it to make it easier to read for the people you want to help you

Comment: I am so sorry, this is my first time use stack overflow , and try to edit it  on the phone, let me give another try to editing the format.

Comment: I tried to help, but well, that is hard. Please read the documentation about "formatting" careful - and please: that **preview** window exists for a reason. Step back, try to write simple "subject verb object" sentences ...

Comment: I understand , sorry about that, and thanks for the advise

Comment: Now lets hope somebody comes by who can help with this ;-)... good luck and farewell.

Comment: @user8327333  please show some code. That is the whole purpose of the observer to observe the database. Whenever data changes in the firebase database your observer in your IOS app is called, updated with the new data from the firebase app and your custom code is run.